# Content Type - Image able to link to other website

Tags: 7, nodes

I had create image field at content type. Without any views module or java-script, am I able create link to other website?

I am not using panel for my website. My question is ONLY related to CONTENT TYPE.

Example: When someone click on the image, it will link to www.google.com

Many Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I link an image to a given URL?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/how-do-i-link-an-image-to-a-given-url)

Comment: @Smalution I not using panel. If I want, I can just use views to solve my problem. It just that I want a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by using any of the below modules :

1. [Image Link Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter)

> This module is the result of the discussions around a requested feature
>   to allow an image field to be displayed with a link to a custom URL

2. [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output
>   image url directly.
>
> Most of the code, maybe more than 90%, is just copy from the drupal
>   core. I think it is stable enough.
>
> I have created a content type, and add an image field instance to it,
>   later i use views to export the data of this content type.And i want
>   to output the data,then i could import it into another drupal 7 site
>   with feeds module. What i need is the url of the image field, but i
>   could not export the image url directly. That is why i create this
>   small module.

3. [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link)

> The link module can be count to the top 50 modules in Drupal
>   installations and provides a standard custom content field for links.
>   With this module links can be added easily to any content types and
>   profiles and include advanced validating and different ways of storing
>   internal or external links and URLs. It also supports additional link
>   text title, site wide tokens for titles and title attributes, target
>   attributes, css class attribution, static repeating values, input
>   conversion, and many more.

Comment: Image Link Formatter works well for me. May I know where to insert target="_blank" ? (It is for open a new window when the link is clicked)

Comment: You need to check the configuration setting of the module or check setting at the time of field creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Link Image Field" module.
After enabling this module when you add a new content type you can see "LInk Image" in the field type drop down.
You will be able to set the maximum,resolution,file extensions,default image,whether to open the link in new tab or not etc.